# split in R and 'for' loop

Tags: r, loops, split

I have a small problem with `loop 'for'` in **R**.

I'm splitting the data regarding one of columns. I want to apply `'for' loop` for splitted file.

How can I do that?

```
input_data <- read.csv2("C:/Users/justyna.andrulewicz/Desktop/R estimator/data2.csv", sep=",")
data <- as.data.frame(input_data)
z <-data$Id
zz <-split(data, z, drop = FALSE)
```

I can define as an object one particular group like that:

```
zz_1<-zz[[1]]
```

but it's not enough for me :D because in my problem I don't know how many groups it will be in splitted file.

Please give any suggestion to me .

Comment: it’s unclear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: `lapply(zz, FUN=...)` is your friend. (`sapply()` is similar). BTW:  
The result of `read.csv2()` is a dataframe, i.e. there is no need for `data <- as.data.frame(input_data)`. Short: `zz <- split(input_data, input_data$Id)`

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can create indexes like this

```
for (i in 1: length(z)){
z[[i]]
}
```

Edit:

as Konrad Rudolph suggest:

Better yet, of course, is to iterate over the object directly. In this case, just do

```
 for (i in z){
print(i) # or do whatever you want    
}
```

Comment: You should generally (always?) avoid using `1 : length(…)` because it will do the wrong thing for empty collections. Instead, you should use `seq_along(…)`. Better yet, of course, is to iterate over the object directly. In this case, just do `for (i in z)`.